# How to append item instead of just pasting it

Tags: javascript

```js
const Sheet = [
        {
            "Code": "A-0-1", 
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803054728.jpg",
            "Title": "U.S.S. Constitution",
            "Price": "$34",
            "InStock": "7"
        },
   ]
   
const productsEl = document.querySelector(".Sheet");

function getProducts() {
    Sheet.forEach((product) => {
        productsEl.innerHTML += `<div class="productContainer">
            <div class="img">
                <img src=${product.UPC} alt="Image Unavailable" height="170px;" width="170px">
            </div>
            <div class="itemdesc">
                <h2 class="itemName" id="itemName">${product.Title}</h2>
                <h4 class="price"><span id="price">${product.Price}</span></h4>
                <div class="desc">
                    <p id="desc">${product.Code}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock">
                    <p> ${product.InStock} Units</p>
            </div>
            <div class="addToCart" onclick="addToCart(this);">
                <button id="addToCart" > Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
    </div>`; 
    })
}
getProducts(); 

let numUnit = document.getElementById("#Unit")
let itemTitle = document.getElementById("item")
let itemPrice = document.getElementById("$Price")

function addToCart(button) {
    const parent = button.closest('.productContainer'),
    Title = parent.querySelector('#itemName')
    Price = parent.querySelector('#price')
    Code = parent.querySelector('#desc')

    itemTitle.textContent = Title.innerText + ' ' + Code.innerText
    itemPrice.textContent = Price.innerText
        

    //let itemInput = document.createElement('input')
    //itemInput.value = numUnit.innerText
    numUnit.textContent = '1'
}
```

```html
        <div class="itemUl">
            <ul>
                <li id="Units">Units:<span id="#Unit"></span></li>
                <li id="Items">Item:<span id="item"></span></li>
                <li id="Price">Price:<span id="$Price"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Sheet">
    </div>
```

What can I change in order to append the task instead of just pasting it in my cart? Currently, I add it to my cart but if press on another object it replace it not add it. By the way, I have a lot of objects in My "Sheet" object I just put one to save space.

Comment: Can you explain what you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a `<Component />` and append the items from `Sheet[]` in your `.Sheet` element.

**CartItem Component**

```js
function CartItem({ code, UPC, title, price, inStock } = {}) {
  const card = document.createElement('div')
  card.classList.add('card')

  const cardImg = document.createElement('img')
  cardImg.classList.add('card-img')
  cardImg.src = UPC

  const cardBody = document.createElement('div')
  cardBody.classList.add('card-body')

  const cardTitle = document.createElement('h2')
  cardTitle.classList.add('card-title')
  cardTitle.innerText = title

  const cardText = document.createElement('h2')
  cardText.classList.add('card-text')
  cardText.innerText = price

  const cardDesc = document.createElement('card-desc')
  cardDesc.classList.add('card-desc')
  cardDesc.innerText = code

  const cardSticker = document.createElement('card-sticker')
  cardSticker.classList.add('card-sticker')
  cardSticker.innerText = inStock
  
  cardBody.append(cardTitle, cardText, cardDesc, cardSticker)
  card.append(cardImg, cardBody)

  return card
}
```

and then use it as this

```js
Sheet.map((item) => {
  productsEl.appendChild(CartItem({...item}))
})
```

Comment: I get the error parameter 1 is not a type of node, how do I fix it?

Comment: @Kunal Tanwar I think it should be `productsEl.appendChild(CartItem({...item}))` right?. btw, is there a reason for sending a copy of the object using `{...item}`, can't we directly send the `item`?.

Comment: @kiro just change it to `productsEl.appendChild(CartItem({...item}))`

Comment: It still gives me alot of errors, do I put both code snippets in my main js sheet?

Comment: and also how do I link it to my addToCart button?

Comment: as @IsmailShaikh said I updated the code I forgot to specify the `CartItem` component.